# Add COM Reference to a project: How to update the list of available references in VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I used to write small codes in VB.net which requires adding and importing specific references. I have installed and registered many dlls on my developing PC, but when I go to "Add Reference" dialog box, only some of them appears in the list of available references.

For instance for one specific product, I have installed the dlls of version 8, 9 and 10, but only the version 8 is listed: the other 2 are missing and I have to use the "Browse" option to add them to my project.

[This is the list of References available in the "Add References" combo box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBO7w.png)

My question is: 
How can it be that not all of the references installed on my PC appears in the combo list? How can I make Visual Studio to actualize the list of existing references?

Thank you for your time and best regards,

Ignacio PdeA
Lebanon

Answer (score 1):

A pretty common bug in a COM component is that the author forgets to change the LIBID or the binary type library version when he creates a new version of the component.  He changed the [helpstring] attribute of the library but that's just a string for humans and plays no role at compile or runtime.  It is a mistake that is a lot less drastic than forgetting to change the CLSID guids.  There are still decent odds that the component works okay at runtime since the type library isn't that commonly used at runtime.  You might however have trouble when you use the component from a worker thread.

But not on a dev machine, registering an older version is going to overwrite the entry in the TypeLib registry key.  In other words, you can only ever see the one you registered last.  Easy to miss by the author, he usually only ever works on the latest version.

This is something you ought to investigate deeper.  Given that he forgot to change the LIBID, he might also have forgotten to change the CLSID and IID guids.  And that produces raging DLL Hell, your program is likely to get the wrong version of the component at runtime without noticing.  Always *very* hard to troubleshoot, the end user is often the hapless victim.  Run OleView.exe from the Visual Studio Command Prompt and use File > View Typelib on the old and new DLLs.  That decompiles the type library back to IDL, you can clearly see the guids.  Double check that the guids have changed.

Do let the author know about this mistake, send him an email.  He can't fix the old mistake anymore but he can at least get it right in the future.  Meanwhile, re-registering the component version you want to target is a workaround of sorts.  You have *lots* of good reasons to only ever use the last version.